# Need help with non-recursive definition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

So I'm trying to find a non-recursive definition for $b_n$.   I'm given $$b_0=1$$ $$b_{n+1}=2b_n-1$$

Does this mean I'm trying to find a number for $b_n$ that fits that algorithm?

**Update:**

Proof by induction.  Let P(n) be that for any $n$, $b_n=1$.

As our base case, we prove P(0), that $b_0=1$, which is obvious from the problem.

For our inductive step, assume for some n ∈ N that P(n) holds.  We prove that P(n+1) holds.

$$b_{n+1}=2b_n-1$$
$$b_n=(b_{n+1}+1)/2$$

**I'm not sure what to do next here.**

Comment: What is $b_1$? $b_2$? This might be the easiest recursion problem in the world. :)

Comment: In many problems, it is useful to *calculate* a little, to get some concrete notion of what is going on.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've actually updated the question with where I'm at so far :)  I understand why this works, I just have a hard time formalizing the proof itself.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I've updated my question with my current progress.

Comment: Let $P(n)$ be the assertion that $a_n=1$. We show by induction that $P(n)$ holds for every non-negative integer $n$. It is clear that $P(0)$ holds. We show that for any non-negative integer $k$, **if** $P(k)$ holds, **then** $P(k+1)$ holds. So $a_k=1$. But then $a_{k+1}=2a_k-1=(2)(1)-1=1$, so $P(k+1)$ holds. The end, terminado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align*}
b_0 & = &1\\
b_1 & = 2b_0 -1 = (2\cdot 1)-1=&1\\
b_2 & = 2b_1 -1 = (2\cdot 1)-1=&1\\
 &\,\vdots& \vdots\,
\end{align*}$$

Comment: So $b_n$ is always 1?

Comment: Yes. Can you prove that it is? One method would be with induction.

Comment: Because I am given $P(0)$, am I supposed to use $P(1)$ as the base case instead?

Comment: If you prefer to start with $1$, why not just declare that $P(n)$ is the statement
$$b_{n-1}\,\text{ is equal to }1\;?$$

Comment: Why $b_{n-1}=1$ instead of $b_n=1$?

Comment: I suggested that because it sounds like you are more comfortable starting induction with $P(1)$ than $P(0)$. It doesn't actually matter where you start. For any given number $k$, if you know that $P(k)$ is true, and that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ for all $n\geq k$, then you know that $P(n)$ is true for all $n\geq k$.

Comment: I'm ok with starting with P(0) instead of P(1).  I thought we couldn't use P(0) because the problem says that $b_0=1$ which I didn't think was helpful in our proof.

Comment: I've actually updated the question with where I'm at so far :)  I understand why this works, I just have a hard time formalizing the proof itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zev's hint to gain understanding about what you need to prove. Often times you will have a crazy nested expression to help find a closed form of the sequence. This is common strategy.

Here is a formal proof if you need some help/verification.

Let $(b_n)$ be the sequence defined by$$
 b_{n} =\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad n = 0 \\
            2b_{n-1}-1 & \quad n > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Let $P(n)$ be the statement: $1 = b_n$ for all $n\geq 0$.

$\bf Base:$ Let $n=0$. The left hand side of the equation is always $1$ and the right hand side is $b_0 = 1$ by definition of $b_n$. Thus $P(0)$ is true.

$\bf Step:$ Assume $P(n)$ is true. That is $1 = b_n$ for $n\geq0$.

Consider $b_{n+1}$ [We must show that $b_{n+1}=1$]
\begin{align}
b_{n+1} =& 2b_n -1 &\quad \text{by definition of $b_n$}\\
=&2*1 -1 &\quad \text{by the induction hypothesis} \\
=& 1
\end{align}
Thus $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, and therefore by the principle of mathematical induction $1 = b_n$ for all $n \geq 0$